# Why A-frame is not loading OBJ .png textures from Maya.

Tags: aframe, webvr, mtl-file

I created a Maya file when I export it to OBJ with the .obj the .mtl and the texture .png everything is loaded except the textures everything is black. Am I missing something while exporting to maya?
Here is the OBJ and the texture: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3cxqacay9sao1bu/AADtArGP5Pu2qdPY3hJBJ3Yka?dl=0

Thank you!

```html
     
     
    <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="object-obj"   src="objects/ccentercables.obj"></a-asset-item>
      <a-asset-item id="object-mtl" src="objects/ccentercables.mtl"></a-asset-item>
   </a-assets>
   
   <a-obj-model src="#object-obj" mtl="#object-mtl" material="src: #texture"></a-obj-model>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although there is a component for the obj's, and .mtl's, the a-frame team [recommends](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/models.html) the .glTF format as it is designed for webGL.

A-frame's Don McCurdy's pointed out multiple times that .obj's differ from each other, and can be hard to interpret by the webGL engine.

You should try converting the model to glTF with [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter), or [this](https://github.com/Kupoman/blendergltf) exporter. Though they are created for blender...

That's why You should also check out Don's [article](https://www.donmccurdy.com/2017/06/27/exporting-gltf-2-0-from-maya-lt-2/) on exporting .gltf models from maya.